# Detect if a web page has a javascript redirect

Tags: php, javascript, curl

I'm using cURL to access a number of different pages. I want an elegant way of checking if the page has a javascript redirect. I could check for presence of a `window.location` in the body, but because it may be inside a .js file or using a library like jQuery, it seems like any solution wouldn't be perfect. Anyone have any ideas?

Comment: Not (easily) possible with simple curl requests since curl doesn't support javascript.

Comment: Yes, i was thinking more of running markup through a parser, rather than executing it.

Comment: You will need to search for window.location in the code outside function and within functions that are called on page load. Obiously, in all the files included also.

Comment: You could look for `window.location` not only in body but in all files that have `*.js` extensions.

Comment: If you are using a parser (or writing one), you can compile a list of .js files that are in the content of the requested file. With that list, you can download those files and parse them for the presence of a redirect as well. Since you have access to the source when downloading the file in your parser, you would be able to append the base url (extrapolated from the url you used originally) to links used in the document to download them

Comment: You could spider through the included JS files, but that wont help you if they use a different method to redirect or if the JS code is loaded via AJAx (which I have seen)

Comment: Just thinking out loud here: browse the url in a sandboxed environment and capture web requests? Or you could of course write your own Javascript engine ;)

Comment: A shame that cURL can't tell what the resolving URL is. Well it can aparently but perhaps not so much with a JS redirect.

Comment: @popnoodles cURL won't fire the javascript redirect, so there will be no url to resolve

Comment: yeah i realised what i'd written afterwards

Comment: Maybe you could use something like capybara/selenium: http://www.christopherbloom.com/2012/03/12/testing-for-a-redirect-using-capybara-and-selenium-webdriver/

Comment: Dont know them well enough. I see how they would be useful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks to Ikstar for pointing out phantomjs I worked out the following example:

**test.js**

```
var page = require('webpage').create();
var testUrls = [
    "http://www.google.nl",
    "http://www.example.com"
];

function testNextUrl()
{
    var testUrl = testUrls.shift();
    page.open(testUrl, function() {
        var hasRedirect = page.url.indexOf(testUrl) !== 0;
        console.log(testUrl + ": " + hasRedirect.toString());
        if (testUrls.length) {
            testNextUrl();
        } else {
            phantom.exit();
        }
    });
}

testNextUrl();
```

**Result:**

```
D:\Tools\phantomjs-1.7.0-windows>phantomjs test.js
http://www.google.nl: false
http://www.example.com: true
```

Comment: How does your code follow through with JS client side redirects? Wouldn't page.open finish before any JS redirects will run?

Answer (score 0):

You cannot do it by only parsing the script. Only executing will show you he true flow of the page's JS.

One way to imitate the execution is to have different levels of code level which has a redirection. The top most would be under `<script>` tag and any redirects here would be a straight redirect. If any redirects are found inside functions then you have to track the structure of the program and make a guess.

Comment: That depends on what @madphp means by 'has a javascript redirect'... If he only wishes to detect the presence of a redirect, a simple parser like the one I described in the comments of the question would work well. If he want's to know if one exists AND will be executed, he would need to make those guesses.

Comment: Yeah, that's a problem. I wondered if there would a innocuous reason for a window.location in a function. Like redirecting to a mobile version or a non-flash page.

Comment: @renab. Yes and thats why I have given both opinions

Answer (score 0):

Depending on the purpose of using Curl and actually needing the redirect on the page. It is possible to incorporate headless framework like PhantomJS (http://phantomjs.org/) to do the necessary browsing. You would be able to see whether a redirect would happen as well as track any other javascript executing on the page.

Answer (score 0):

It is **impossible** to detect the presence of a redirect just analyzing the webpage source code.

The undecidable [Halting problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Halting_problem) can be encoded in JavaScript. The algorithm may halt, resulting in the generation of a redirect, or run forever. Since we do not know if the code will halt, it is impossible also to decide if the redirect will be executed or not.